# Как изменить цвет с помощью ColorPicker при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. На форме есть элемент ColorPicker, как изменить цвет при нажатии на кнопку.
Так цвет не меняется.

```
DirectionalLight dl = new DirectionalLight();
dl.Color = customCPDirectionalLight.SelectedColor;
```

**Дополнение.**

```
private void ApplyButtonDirectionalLight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    win.customCPDirectionalLight.SelectedColorChanged += new Action<System.Windows.Media.Color> (customCPDirectionalLight_SelectedColorChanged);
}

public void customCPDirectionalLight_SelectedColorChanged(System.Windows.Media.Color obj)
{
    MGroup.Children.Clear();
    DirectionalLight dl = new DirectionalLight();
    dl.Color = (System.Windows.Media.Color) obj;
    MGroup.Children.Add(dl);
}
```

Comment: А цвет чего?

Comment: На форме есть 3D объект у него есть группа MGroup источников света один из них DirectionalLight, как изменить цвет источника при нажатии на кнопку с помощью ColrPicker. При первом нажатии на кнопку изменении не срабатываает.

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: dl.Color = (System.Windows.Media.Color)obj; // вот этот цвет надо поменять на новый выбранный в colorPicker при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: У DirectionalLight точно атрибут Color отвечает за цвет?

Comment: Да именно этот атрибут.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше будет привязать цвет необходимого объекта к ресурсу и менять уже сам ресурс:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
  <Color x:Key="colorLight">#FFFFFF</Color>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DirectionalLight Color="{DynamicResource colorLight}" Direction="-1,-1,-1" />
...
```

И соответственно менять, например:

```
window1.Resources["colorLight"] = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Попробуйте:
dl.Color = new SolidColorBrush(тут цвет);
```